# merge windows 2008r2 AD account with windows 2011 sbs

Tags: sharepoint-2010, active-directory, window, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-sbs

I need to synchronize user account two domains  windows 2008r2 (where there are all accounts) and 2011sbs (does not support trusts) where it is installed sharepoint 2010 and we need users to use the same password.

I read something about [ADMT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc974368(v=ws.10).aspx) but I can not apply to windows 2011 sbs

the best solution would be the merge of the account, another good option would be to change the password directly from Sharepoint or otherwise even from a web pages that speaks in LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

solved with http://changepassword.codeplex.com/ ed support of this guide:
http://www.mnscug.org/blogs/steve-buchanan/181-add-reset-password-to-scsm-2012-self-service-portal